# Composition of Sofer's ink

Tags: tefilin, mezuzah, safrus

What ingredients are currently used in the manufacture of ink for Safrus? Is there a different formulation for the paint that is used to dye tefillin straps/boxes?

Comment: Basically what's been used almost exclusively for the last 1000 years is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_gall_ink (which Rabbenu Tam thought was Pasul) though originally it was more like a vegan version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India_ink

Comment: partial dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9315/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://www.ctc-torah.org/2009/07/the-ingredients-part-iii-dyo-ink/)  seems to be a good page to see.

For a more comprehensive source, see the [Mishkenos Yaakov](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1095&st=&pgnum=53).

For retzuah paint, you can just use shoe polish.  It doesn't require d'yo.

The above linked pages contain recipes for the ink used by most sofrim today, known as מי עפצים וקנקנתום -- oakgall juice and ferrous sulfate. [This post](http://melakhetshamayim.blogspot.com/2011/01/halakha-of-ink.html), written by a very qualified sofer has a recipe.

Comment: So the "hechsheirim" on those markers and little paint applicators are actually superfluous?

Comment: Of course you have to make sure the Shoe Polish you use has no Unkosher ingredients Hence the Hechsher.

Comment: Practically speaking, you don't need a hechsher. As to YS's concern, see Keses Hasofer 23:2 here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41270&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=

Comment: There are older recipes that are slightly different than the one given on the above page, but essentially that is it.  Sofer ink is an iron gall ink.

Comment: DO NOT use shoe polish to darken your Tefillin straps. Many shoe polishes contain animal fat. High quality ones may contain ingredients like mink oil. Shoe dye would probably be ok but shoe polish is an oil based product which always contains some sort of wax/fat/oil and should not be assumed to be kosher.

Comment: @Aaron Shaffier, do you have a source for that?  Especially for where the unkosher ingredient is ancillary?

Comment: @YDK, I would be disappointed in this answer for its lack of actual information, but I see this is one of your first answers on the site (2 and a half years and over 400 answers ago). If you've got the time, would you care to expand it a little so as to be more useful to more readers?

Comment: @YDK Can you include updated hyperlinks? It looks like at least two are now broken. What would be even better is if you could summarize the points in those articles in case the hyperlinks break again in the future.

Comment: Dead link......

Answer (score 3):

The Sta"m Forum has [a page](http://www.stamforum.com/2012/03/dyo-making.html) with a well tested recipe for STA"M ink almost identical to the one in Kol Sofrim. I can't vouch for it because I buy ink, but the person who posted it is a professional who has written several Sifrei Torah.