# Does tefillin marker pen have any requirements?

Tags: tefilin

Lots of Jewish shops sell pens made for the purpose of filling in parts of your tefillin which have lost their blackness.

Do you need to buy a special pen (and if so why) or is it all a con and I can use a sharpie?
Is there a difference between the boxes and the retzuos (straps)?

Comment: I believe the marker needs to be a special one for Tefillin & not any marker, as all items used in Tefillin need to be kosher. The Gemarah leans from a Pasuk in Parshas Bo that everything related to Tefillin needs to be kosher to eat. I wrote as comment however as I don't have the exact Gemarah where this is learned out.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52968/kosher-shoe-polish-to-blacken-tefillin