# Dyo lesafrut - mutar beficha or not

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, safrus

I came across a thread today on the [International Sta"m Forum](http://www.stamforum.com/2012/02/dyo-for-sofrut.html). In the comments, some of the sofrim who frequent the site were debating whether sofer's ink, or *dyo*, need be mutar beficha (permitted to be eaten)?

What are the opinions on the matter and what is the common preference among today's poskim (Ashkenazi and Sephardi)?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2244/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, not quite. I just reviewed that post, and it makes no mention of the issue of whether animal-derived ingredients in dyo must be from beheimot tehorot.