# What is Sta"m ink made from?

Tags: safrus

I have several questions related to Sta"m (Torah, mezuzot tefillin) ink:

- What materials are allowable?
- What materials are typically used to make the ink? Why these materials, specifically? (cheaper, easier to obtain, better quality, etc.)?
- How is it made? (Brief description of the process and / or link to article, video, etc.)
- What does this typically cost? How much is needed, typically for each type of Sta"m?
- Who makes it (is there a major worldwide manufacturer / factory)?
- Can an individual easily make this himself, or is it a complex process?

Comment: The Rambam discusses ink in the beginning of Hilchot Tefillin. Also, iron-gall ink was once very common (it's horrible for the k'tav and the klaf though).

Comment: I believe that the main requirement be that all materials are mutar b'peh

Comment: http://lavlor.blogspot.com/2011/12/ink.html

Comment: Rabbi/sofer Eli Gutnick wrote an article on this. I'll try and find it

Comment: these are relevant to your question http://www.stamforum.com/2012/03/dyo-making.html http://www.stamforum.com/2012/02/dyo-for-sofrut.html http://dio-lanetzach.blogspot.co.il/2009/01/dio-lanetzach.html

Comment: @mbloch I sometimes have trouble accessing certain links from my browser. Tech problems. Can you summarize the main points from that article and post as answer? There's a bounty placed as an incentive :-) No guarantee that you'll get it, but perhaps worth the effort.

Comment: @DanF to access these difficult links, did you try using Google to access the cached version on their servers? Do a Google search for the address of the site (e.g., http://www.stamforum.com/2012/03/dyo-making.html) then click the down arrow on the right of the green site address below the site name. Does it work?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2244/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9315/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82383/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52968/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57921/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://scrolls4all.org/scrolls/kosher-ink/) where they the main ingredients as

> Water, Oak Gall Nut, Gum Arabic, Soot, Logwood, Copper Sulfate or Iron
>   Sulfate. There are many recipes for this ink and many laws the Scribe
>   must follow to produce kosher ink. There is a recent movement among
>   Soferim to stop including the sulfate, either iron or copper, in the
>   ink. They are giving two reasons for this decision. First, the
>   commandment that no product ever used for war, including iron and
>   copper, can be used in writing a Sefer Torah. The second reason is the
>   quick decay of the scroll, 150 years maximum, due to iron gall ink
>   degradation. Many Soferim are simply going back to the soot base ink.
>   It is the sulfate that causes the chemical reaction which results in
>   the degradation of the ink and it is the quality and amount of gum
>   Arabic that causes the ink to crack and fall off the letters.

Nonetheless, the article continues to list a different series of ingredients used more often today:

> - 3 oz oak galls
> - 1 oz logwood shavings
> - 2.2 oz gum arabic
> - 1.9 oz copperas

Rabbi Abramowitz translates the [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Tefillin,_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.1.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) (1:4) Tefillin, Mezuzah v’Sefer Torah

> כֵּיצַד מַעֲשֵׂה הַדְּיוֹ. מְקַבְּצִין הֶעָשָׁן שֶׁל שְׁמָנִים אוֹ
>   שֶׁל זֶפֶת וְשֶׁל שַׁעֲוָה וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן וְגוֹבְלִין אוֹתָן
>   בִּשְׂרַף הָאִילָן וּבִמְעַט דְּבַשׁ וְלוֹתְתִין אוֹתוֹ הַרְבֵּה
>   וְדָכִין אוֹתוֹ עַד שֶׁיֵּעָשֶׂה רְקִיקִין וּמְיַבְּשִׁין אוֹתוֹ
>   וּמַצְנִיעִין אוֹתוֹ. וּבִשְׁעַת כְּתִיבָה שׁוֹרֵהוּ בְּמֵי עֲפָצִים
>   וְכַיּוֹצֵא בּוֹ וְכוֹתֵב בּוֹ. שֶׁאִם תִּמְחָקֶנּוּ יִהְיֶה נִמְחָק.
>   וְזֶהוּ הַדְּיוֹ שֶׁמִּצְוָה מִן הַמֻּבְחָר לִכְתֹּב בּוֹ סְפָרִים
>   תְּפִלִּין וּמְזוּזוֹת. וְאִם כָּתַב שְׁלָשְׁתָּן בְּמֵי עֲפְצָא
>   וְקַנְקַנְתּוֹם שֶׁהוּא עוֹמֵד וְאֵינוֹ נִמְחָק כְּשֵׁרִיִם:
>   [Saying:](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos-2-mishneh-torah/379-the-ink/) 
>   Ink is made by gathering ingredients like oils, tar, wax, etc., and
>   kneading them with tree sap and a drop of honey. It is moistened,
>   crushed into flat cakes, dried, then stored. When one wants to write
>   with it, he soaks one of the cakes in gallnut juice or something
>   similar, after which he would be able to write with it. If one tries
>   to erase it, it would erase. This is the most desirable ink to use
>   when writing sefarim, tefillin and mezuzos, but if one use gallnut
>   juice or vitriol, which cannot be erased, it is valid.

OU offers an additional [shiur](https://www.ou.org/torah/gemara/daf-yomi/daf-in-halacha/ink-in-halacha-2/) on the topic as well.

As far as purchasing the ink, there are a couple of websites offering already made ink. For instance, this [site](http://www.hasofer.com/page.pl?p=sofer-supplies) offers 200 grams of ink for about $25.